# LabelEncoder().fit_transform vs. pd.get_dummies for categorical coding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

It was recently brought to my attention that if you have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
   A      B   C
0  0   Boat  45
1  1    NaN  12
2  2    Cat   6
3  3  Moose  21
4  4   Boat  43
```

You can encode the categorical data automatically with `pd.get_dummies`:

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Which yields this:

```
   A   C  B_Boat  B_Cat  B_Moose
0  0  45     1.0    0.0      0.0
1  1  12     0.0    0.0      0.0
2  2   6     0.0    1.0      0.0
3  3  21     0.0    0.0      1.0
4  4  43     1.0    0.0      0.0
```

I typically use `LabelEncoder().fit_transform` for this sort of task before putting it in `pd.get_dummies`, but if I can skip a few steps that'd be desirable.

Am I losing anything by simply using `pd.get_dummies` on my entire dataframe to encode it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can skip the use of `LabelEncoder` if you only want to encode string features. On the other hand if you have a categorical column of integers (instead of strings) then `pd.get_dummies` will leave as it is (see your A or C column for example). In that case you should use [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). Ideally `OneHotEncoder` would support both integer and strings but this is being [worked on at the moment](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7327).

Comment: Okay thank you, this confirms my intuitions and I had already made the appropriate changes to my dataset to account for this so all's well.